# A movie about a Soviet(?) ballet composer?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for this movie, but I barely remember it. It seemed to be from the 2000's and I'm not sure but I think it wasn't in English.

It was a very cute film, about an ageing Soviet composer (maybe Russian? Or German? Don't remember) that had written some ballet or orchestral piece that never got to be played, or maybe he was censored back in the day, and being now in a democratic country he was somehow convinced (maybe by a female love interest?) to finish the piece and... they gather an orchestra and all of the players are old people that used to play for this composer many years ago. And they get to play to some big, renowned theatre and the composer finally gains recognition and respect. Oh and I think the composer and the musicians travelled in a ratty old van, maybe a Volkswagen Camper or something similar, along with all their instruments.

Comment: Reminds me of [Le Concert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Concert) from 2009, but I'm not sure it all fits.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks a lot. My memories were very very vague.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this. Glad you found it; I'll put it up.

Answer (score 3):

This generally describes the French comedy [Le Concert](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1320082/combined) from 2009:

> Thirty years ago, Andrei Simoniovich Filipov, the renowned conductor of the Bolshoi orchestra, was fired for hiring Jewish musicians. Now a mere cleaning man at the Bolshoi, he learns by accident that the Châtelet Theater in Paris invites the Bolshoi orchestra to play there. He decides to gather together his former musicians and to perform in Paris in the place of the current Bolshoi orchestra.